# How to set up 2 level deep nested resources controller in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested-resources

How to set up 2 level deep nested resources controller in Rails 4?

I added the controller paths. I am not sure if that is what was asked.

Ive tried it using `class Presupuestos::Ordenes::OrdeneItemsController` but it returns an error:

```
     ActionController::RoutingError at /presupuestos/2/ordenes/1/orden_items/new
        uninitialized constant Ordenes.

ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher#controller
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb, line 62 
ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher#controller
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb, line 57
ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher#serve
```

**Controller Paths**

```
presupuesto_ordene_orden_items GET    /presupuestos/:presupuesto_id/ordenes/:ordene_id/orden_items(.:format)          presupuestos/ordenes/orden_items#index
                                   POST   /presupuestos/:presupuesto_id/ordenes/:ordene_id/orden_items(.:format)          presupuestos/ordenes/orden_items#create
 new_presupuesto_ordene_orden_item GET    /presupuestos/:presupuesto_id/ordenes/:ordene_id/orden_items/new(.:format)      presupuestos/ordenes/orden_items#new
edit_presupuesto_ordene_orden_item GET    /presupuestos/:presupuesto_id/ordenes/:ordene_id/orden_items/:id/edit(.:format) presupuestos/ordenes/orden_items#edit
     presupuesto_ordene_orden_item GET    /presupuestos/:presupuesto_id/ordenes/:ordene_id/orden_items/:id(.:format)      presupuestos/ordenes/orden_items#show
                                   PATCH  /presupuestos/:presupuesto_id/ordenes/:ordene_id/orden_items/:id(.:format)      presupuestos/ordenes/orden_items#update
                                   PUT    /presupuestos/:presupuesto_id/ordenes/:ordene_id/orden_items/:id(.:format)      presupuestos/ordenes/orden_items#update
                                   DELETE /presupuestos/:presupuesto_id/ordenes/:ordene_id/orden_items/:id(.:format)      presupuestos/ordenes/orden_items#destroy
```

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :presupuestos do
  collection { post :import }
  resources :ordenes, controller: 'presupuestos/ordenes' do
    resources :orden_items, controller: 'presupuestos/ordenes/orden_items'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the full error being returned?

Comment: check out namespaces [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html)

Comment: Oh.. My mistake I meant the paths of the files ^^. So for example `/Users/johndoe/Developer/...`. If this is a Git project and open source than you can upload it to Github and give me the URL to the repo. But DON'T do this if you don't want to make the code base public!

Comment: Thanks this is the URL: https://github.com/davefogo/ideapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the problem.

Here is the updated [Repo](https://github.com/tobiasfeistmantl/ideapp). I haven't tested it since I haven't `Postgres` installed on this machine.

The problem was a problem with the directory.

Your controller is nested into the `Presupuestos::Ordenes` module but the file was located in `app/controllers/presupuestos/orden_items/`. Since rails' `Autoload` feature expect that the file is located in `app/controllers/presupuestos/ordenes/` it can't find it.

Just pull the changes of the [Repo](https://github.com/tobiasfeistmantl/ideapp) or rename the folder by yourself. `app/controllers/presupuestos/orden_items/`=> `app/controllers/presupuestos/ordenes/`